# How is the formula for the variance and covariance of residuals derived?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, variance, covariance, linear-regression

The first formula I have is as follows : $\operatorname{var}(\widehat\varepsilon )=\sigma^2(−)$ where $=(^)^{−1}$ and $\widehat\varepsilon$ is the residual. Furthermore, I am having trouble understanding how $\operatorname{cov}((−))=\sigma^2(−)$ as well. Here, $(−)=−̂$  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this context "cov" and "var" are synonyms. Some people call this matrix "cov" because its entries are covariances and some (William Feller among them) call it "var" because it is a higher-dimensional generalization of the variance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you do and don't know about all this, so I will answer only a bit of this:

The matrix $I-H$ is symmetric and idempotent. "Symmetric" means it's its own transpose: $(I-H)'=I-H.$ "Idempotent" means it's its own square: $(I-H)^2=I-H.$

Generally if $U\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}$ is random vector and $\operatorname{var}(U) = \Sigma\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times n}$ is a constant (i.e. non-random) matrix, then $\operatorname{var}(AU) = A\Sigma A',$ where $A'$ is the transpose of $A.$

So you have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(\widehat{\varepsilon\,}) & = \operatorname{var}((I-H)Y) \\[6pt] & = (I-H)(\sigma^2 I) (I-H)' \\[6pt]
& = \sigma^2(I-H)(I-H)' \\[6pt]
& = \sigma^2 (I-H)(I-H) \\[6pt]
& = \sigma^2(I-H).
\end{align}